# Character Encoding of HTML 4

Tags: html, internet-explorer, character-encoding, special-characters, html4

I have designed a web page using HTML 4.
in which meta information is as follows:

```
meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"
```

When I try to save this address using web page "900 René-Lévesque Blvd W", which includes special characters like "é", it gets saved as this: "900 RenÃ©-LÃ©vesque Blvd W".

Note: this behaviour is observed only in IE.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using in conjunction with HTML4? (And if I may ask, why HTML4?)

Comment: If you pasted this content in from MS word you'll experience this problem because Word does not default to UTF-8. Bonne chance.

Comment: There are various reasons why UTF-8 encoded data would get interpreted as windows-1252, which is what seems to be happening here. For example, in the absence of Byte Order Mark, character encoding information in HTTP headers overrides `meta` tag info. Please provide more information, such as HTTP headers sent by the server.